# Nested for-loop to replace to replace values

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, nested

I am trying to clean a data frame from a large study.  There are 12 study subjects with the wrong start date entered in a column named "startdate."  I've created a vector with the study ids of the 12 subjects that need to be edited called "badids."

```
badids<-c(41, 4169, 12004, 7768, 180, 78, 4082, 430, 585, 1313, 449, 9074)
```

I've also created a vector of the 12 correct dates for these 12 subjects called "correctdates."

I can replace the incorrect dates one by one using a the following command:

```
dat[dat$Study.ID.Number.==badids[1], "startdate"]<-correctdates[1]
```

But that's inefficient.

A nested for loop seemed like a better solution so I tried:

```
for(i in 1:12)
{
    for (j in 1:12) {                    
        dat[dat$Study.ID.Number.==badids[i], "startdate"]<-correctdates[j]
    }
}
```

I don't get an error message from this loop, but it also doesn't correct the start dates in the data frame.  What am I missing?  Is there a better way to do this entirely that I should be considering especially when dealing with more than just 12 edits in the future?  Thanks for teaching me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, then the problem in your code is that you are doing one `for` loop too many. You code seems to be replacing each of the `badid`'s subject's `startdate` twelve times. As a result, they all end up having the same value: the last value in `startdate`.   Removing the inner loop should do the trick:

```
for(i in 1:12)
{       
    dat$startdate[dat$Study.ID.Number.==badids[i]] <- correctdates[i]
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  That's exactly what I was going for.  Thank you Andrea.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `match` here to match the badids with their corresponding correct date.  To only match those badids you can use `%in%`to check if they exist in Study.ID. Number in an `ifelse` statement.

This should work:

```
ifelse(dat$Study.ID.Number. %in% badids,   
       correctdates[match(dat$Study.ID.Number. , badids)],
       dat$startdate )
```

EDIT:

try now e.g. this quick demo seems to work for me:

```
set.seed(1)
badids = c(2,4)
correctdates = c(100,200)
dat <- data.frame(Study.ID.Number. = rep(c(1:5),5),
          startdate = sample(1:10,25,T))

dat$startdate  <- ifelse(dat$Study.ID.Number. %in% badids,   
       correctdates[match(dat$Study.ID.Number. , badids)],
       dat$startdate )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.  The dates in dat remain the same.

Comment: @user2230555 pretty sure it works- I just tested it and it saves time not putting it into a loop

Comment: The demo works beautifully.  Not sure why I'm not seeing the same result with my dataframe.